# How do I use a quartz crystal in an oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, crystal

How can I get a quartz crystal to make square waves at 4.096MHz? So far I have the 4.096MHz quartz crystal and this schematic I saw:

[image]

Where can you find an amplifier with a single input and what voltage should I use?

Comment: Please tell us what you've got so far and what exact problem you ran in to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a Pierce Oscillator similar to that shown in your question:

[image: Pierce Oscllator]

The "single input amplifier" is usually a simple CMOS inverting gate, like the 74HC7404 (6 inverters in one package), [SN74HC14D](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/sn74hc14d/ic-hex-inverter-schmitt-trigger/dp/2374249) (single inverter) or similar.
Voltage can be something within the operating range of the IC, such as 5V. You may need to add a series resistor to limit the crystal drive (you need to check the crystal datasheet for manufacturer recommendations)
Here is a circuit with typical component values:

[image: Pierce Oscillator 2]

Note the series R mentioned above. The above came from this [Fairchild App](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-340.pdf) Note which goes into some detail on the design process.

You can only pull the frequency of a crystal oscillator a very small amount, so you will need a 4.096MHz crystal. Either that or you will need to use something else such as a [PLL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop).

Comment: I wonder where is the input(VCC) and where is the output in "FIGURE 3. Typical Gate Oscillator"

Comment: Vcc and GND to the gate are not shown. The output is at the right hand side of the gate (pointy side with circle) - you can buffer it with another gate if required as shown in your example.

Comment: @Cristi: if Oli's answer answers your question you can accept, so that others know the problem is solved. The button with the check mark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an op amp in your circuit, ore use a 555 to generate square weaves

or do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally Xtals below 30MHz are fundamental parallel mode resonance like LC expect Q is 3K and high impedance 180deg phase shift at resonance. THis means you need negative feedback using an inverter not a series mode with a non-inverter. Try both buffered x1000 gain and unbuffered x10 gain inverter CMOS chips and ensure spurious harmonic oscillator modes are avoided.The Xtal Q has enough gain with CMOS gain of 10x to get a square wave when feedback R is high Z.

[image]

Let Rf = 1~10 MΩ to self bias input to Vcc/2
let Rs = 10kΩ and C1 = 30~47pF or so.
Let C2 = 100~1000pF in series with Varicap cathode while anode is to ground for reverse bias V vs cap control. Choose 0~12Vdc control range for varicap (or more) and select C1 to tune centre F.

I know this is a lot to take in a short paragraph so ask a Q? or read up on parallel VCXO's.

Here is a simple reference to appreciate Crystals more.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31002a.pdf