# Problem in Clapp oscillator

Tags: oscillator, bjt

[image]

I've set up this circuit on breadboard ( C1 being electrolytic and others disk) with Q1 as 2n3904. The simulation is perfectly fine and the oscillator works in the simulator as expected. However, the situation with the actual circuit is a bit different.

No matter what inductor L2 I choose, the frequency is always 210 KHz. I switched 47 uH with 4.7 and 10 uH; but its always 210 KHz. Even more disturbing is the fact that even if I remove some components from the circuit, ( I removed C1 and L2, not simultaneously though), and measure from L1, its still 210 KHz. To make matters worse, I just randomly waved the oscilloscope probe in air. and it still records 210 KHz ( I even put the probe on my head, and it seemed like my brain generates 210 KHz as well ! ).

So whats going wrong here ? And whats the deal with 210 KHz ?

Comment: Repeating your sim with a 2N3904 called out explicitly, I get about 250kHz. What frequency is it supposed to oscillate at?

Comment: Its frequency is supposed to be 1/(2*3.14*√(L2*C4) ), and therefore should vary as I change L2.

Answer (score 1):

I think your test equipment has a problem... what happens if you touch the probe with one finger and approach a power outlet (50-60HZ) with your other hand? If you still read 210KHz instead of 50-60Hz, you **definitely** have a test-equipment problem. Do you maybe have a "data hold" function engaged?

Comment: Will I stay alive after trying this ?

Comment: Don't **insert** your finger into the power outlet, only **approach** it. Your body should pick up quite a strong signal from just being near the outlet.

Comment: No. It shows 50 Hz. So I think equipment is fine. ( If my body could pickup signal from power outlet, then maybe it is picking up from ckt as well; its amplitude is 20 V.But whats up with 210 KHz. Any clue ?)

Comment: That's an oddball frequency, but it **might** correlate to an electronic fluorescent ballast, if one is running in that room or a nearby room. Otherwise, it's a homing signal from the Mother Ship. 8)

Comment: You mean to say noise ? Isnt 200 khz a bit too high for noise ?

Comment: Not at all - some circuitry generates RFI well into the MHz region. I've even seen failing voltage regulators (78- series) generate significant noise in that region.

Comment: So that means..in reality my oscillator is not oscillating and oscilloscope is picking up this noise..? Then what should I do to get my ckt working (since it simulated fine, I have no clue what to do next) ? More importantly, how to avoid that pesky frequency from entering observations ?

Comment: Try turning off any likely noise sources (fluorescent lights, etc) nearby and probing your circuit again, now that you've observed 50/60Hz noise, using all original parts values. If you're still not seeing a frequency you expect, check your transistor to be sure it's still good. I'd imagine that your oscillator **should** be able to easily mask that noise when it's working right.